# Material UI Drawer graying out, but not sliding into view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, navbar

I am pretty new to SD, and am practicing on my free time to get better so all advice is welcome (but give it to me like I am an elementary student). Im am just trying to get Drawer Component feature to work and then build off of it to fit my needs, but at the moment the Drawer Component  is not functioning properly even when I almost completely copy and paste the Javascript from [Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com). I have the AppBar displaying nicely and when i click the MenuRoundedIcon, the display grays out, but the drawer doesn't slide in from the left. If i click again, it returns to normal. I cannot get the sidebar to slide in with the eventual list of Home, About, Connect. Here is my code:

App.js

```
import './App.css';
// pages
import Home from './components/pages/Home'; 
import About from './components/pages/About'; 
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import ConnectCard from './components/ConnectCard';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const myTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#347055',
      main: '#024D2B',
      dark:'#01351e'
    },
    secondary: {
      dark: '#b28900',
      main: '#ffc400',
      light: '#ffcf33'
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiCard: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          maxWidth: '55rem',
          margin: '2rem',
        }
      }
    },
    MuiButton: {
    }
  }
  });




function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
      <NavBar />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <main>
          <Routes>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
            <Route path='/contact' element={<ConnectCard />} />
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

NavBar.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

// Material UI
import { AppBar, Box, Toolbar, IconButton, Typography, Button, MenuItem, List, ListItem, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from "@mui/material";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";

// Icons
import MenuRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MenuRounded';
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import InfoIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Info';
import ConnectWithoutContactIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ConnectWithoutContact';

// Components
import ConnectCard  from './ConnectCard';


// const 

export default function NavBar(){
    const [drawerState, setDrawerState] = useState({
        top: false,
        right: false,
        bottom: false,
        left: false
    });
    console.log(`Drawer`, drawerState)
    const toggleDrawer = (anchor, openStatus) => (event) => {
        if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
            return;
        }

        setDrawerState({ ...drawerState, [anchor]: openStatus })
    }
    
    const list = (anchor) => {
        <Box
            sx={{ width: anchor === 'top' || anchor === 'bottom' ? 'auto' : 250 }}
            // role='presentation'
            onClick={() => toggleDrawer(anchor, false)} //this is where i will put the redirect
            onKeyDown={() => toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
        >
            <List>
                {['Home', 'About', 'Connect'].map((text) => (
                    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                {<HomeIcon />}
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary={text} />
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        </Box>
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Button
                            color={"secondary"}
                            onClick={toggleDrawer('left', true)}
                            edge='start'
                        >{<MenuRoundedIcon />}
                        </Button>
                        <Drawer
                            open={drawerState.left}
                            direction={'left'}
                            onClose={() => setDrawerState({ left: false })}
                        >{list('left')}
                        </Drawer>
                        <Typography
                            variant="h2"
                            component="h4"
                            sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                            align={'center'}
                        >
                            Lee R. Roberts
                        </Typography>
                    </Toolbar>
                    
                </AppBar>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
};import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

// Material UI
import { AppBar, Box, Toolbar, IconButton, Typography, Button, MenuItem, List, ListItem, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from "@mui/material";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";

// Icons
import MenuRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MenuRounded';
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
import InfoIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Info';
import ConnectWithoutContactIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ConnectWithoutContact';

// Components
import ConnectCard  from './ConnectCard';


// const 

export default function NavBar(){
    const [drawerState, setDrawerState] = useState({
        top: false,
        right: false,
        bottom: false,
        left: false
    });
    console.log(`Drawer`, drawerState)
    const toggleDrawer = (anchor, openStatus) => (event) => {
        if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
            return;
        }

        setDrawerState({ ...drawerState, [anchor]: openStatus })
    }
    
    const list = (anchor) => {
        <Box
            sx={{ width: anchor === 'top' || anchor === 'bottom' ? 'auto' : 250 }}
            // role='presentation'
            onClick={() => toggleDrawer(anchor, false)} //this is where i will put the redirect
            onKeyDown={() => toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
        >
            <List>
                {['Home', 'About', 'Connect'].map((text) => (
                    <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
                        <ListItemButton>
                            <ListItemIcon>
                                {<HomeIcon />}
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText primary={text} />
                        </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        </Box>
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Button
                            color={"secondary"}
                            onClick={toggleDrawer('left', true)}
                            edge='start'
                        >{<MenuRoundedIcon />}
                        </Button>
                        <Drawer
                            open={drawerState.left}
                            direction={'left'}
                            onClose={() => setDrawerState({ left: false })}
                        >{list('left')}
                        </Drawer>
                        <Typography
                            variant="h2"
                            component="h4"
                            sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                            align={'center'}
                        >
                            Lee R. Roberts
                        </Typography>
                    </Toolbar>
                    
                </AppBar>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
};
```

Even when I set the  all I get is the grayed overlay. Why doesn't the sidebar slide in as it does in the link above when you click 'left' or 'right'.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like an idiot... If I place the  within the  I get the Slide and the list that I want... Im confused why that wasn't in the docs. Did I miss that step somewhere?

```
 return (
    <>
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <Button
                        color={"secondary"}
                        onClick={toggleDrawer('left', true)}
                        edge='start'
                    >{<MenuRoundedIcon />}
                    </Button>
                    <Drawer
                        open={drawerState.left}
                        direction={'left'}
                        onClose={() => setDrawerState({ left: false })}
                    >
                        <List>
                            {['Home', 'About', 'Connect'].map((text) => (
                                <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
                                    <ListItemButton>
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            {<HomeIcon />}
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                                    </ListItemButton>
                                </ListItem>
                            ))}
                        </List>
                    </Drawer>
                    <Typography
                        variant="h2"
                        component="h4"
                        sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                        align={'center'}
                    >
                        Lee R. Roberts
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
                
            </AppBar>
        </Box>
    </>
);
```